# JavaScript debugger to ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, gulp

Is it possible to debug ReactJS and/or compiled JS (Gulp) using `debugger`?

When im building a huge function that has alot of methods i NEED to use `debugger` to see my functions flow, I tried using `VSC` plugins for debugging but I really didn't understand how to use them.

```
class Human {
    constructor(object){
        this.data = object;
        this.name = this.data.name;
        this.age = this.data.age;
        this.gender = this.data.gender;
    }

    talk = function(string){
        console.log(`A ${this.gender} is saying: ${string}`)
    }

    birthday = function(int){debugger // i really like using debugger for methods
        this.age = this.age += int;
    }
}

const person = new Human({
    name: 'Sara',
    age: 19,
    gender: 'Female'
})

person.talk('Hello') // A Female is saying: Hello
person.birthday(1) // When compiled the debugger is removed
```

If I really can't use `debugger` in these scenarios what other solution do you guys use?

My `gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

const myFiles = [
    './app/js/vendors/*.js',
    './app/js/controller.js',
    './app/js/functions.js',
    './app/js/model.js',
    './app/js/view.js'
]


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(cssnano({zindex: false}))
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
})


gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(myFiles)
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})

gulp.task('go', function(){
    gulp.watch('./app/styles/*.scss', gulp.series('sass')),
    gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
    return
});
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use `birthday` method. What do you want to show using this example?

Comment: *"is it possible"* ... certainly. Call the birthday method and walk through it

Comment: Ok. i updated the problem

Comment: Do you specifically need the debugging to occur in vscode? Maybe your gulp build configuration removes your `debugger` statements. Do you have a development specific build configuration (which outputs sourcemaps and does not minimize your code)?

Comment: No, I just started using Gulp so didn't really try that yet, but what about ReactJs? Doesn't react remove the debugger when compiled?

Comment: React does not compile anything, a gulp plugin (probably babel) is transpilling your jsx to plain js (and most likely from this js to es5). Debugger statement will not be removed if there's no plugin to do so. Look further into your gulp configuration.

Comment: Are you also using a bundler like webpack or rollup? If so could you add their configuration to your question?

Comment: just added my gulp file

Comment: You can try removing ```.pipe(uglify())``` from you gulp js task. Now the buldle.js file will be more readable and if you put any debugger statement in react, it will stop the interpreter and you can debug from there.

Comment: Doesn't react-app compile the JSX? Is it possible to not use its compiler?